# Font family preview in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

I've the initialization of tinyMCE, where I've included new fonts in addition to the default ones:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  selector: '#htmleditor',
  theme: 'modern',
  width: '100%',
  height: 500,
  fontsize_formats: "4pt 6pt 8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
  content_css: ['fonts/CI.css'],
  font_formats: '[*DEFAULTFONTLISTOMITTED*]
  + NewFont1=NewFont1,NewFont1;NewFont2=NewFont2,Impact;NewFont3=NewFont3,NewFont3;',
});
```

As you can see, the structure for new fonts is:

```
NewFontName=NewFontNameClassInCSS,NewFontStyleForList
```

Well, if I put a font family that exists, for example Impact (second example) it changes the style BUT if I put one *NewFont style* it doesn't affects the text, it just stays in default style. **Important: Everything works except the font preview**

Any thoughts about this problem?

CI.css content:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'NewFontName';
  src: url('NewFontName.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

[jsFiddle example using custom font](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/przvoq) Thanks skobaljic

Comment: Any console warnings or errors?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Nothing, font list just don't get the new styles. They work if you select them (changin the font style in the editor) but the font style appearance is default.

Comment: Can you please provide jsFiddle?

Comment: Have you checked [this fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/przvoq)?

Comment: @skobaljic As you can see in the jsFiddle the dropdown for custom font item uses the font-style not using the font-family listed (Indie flower).

Comment: @NavjotAhuja The jsFiddle that skobaljic posted could be useful for you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/przvoq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't back any of this up with documentation, but if we disect the codepen provided by @skobalijc, we can see that what TinyMCE itself is made up of some elements inserted directly into the DOM which make up the menus and UI, and an `iframe` for the content area.

What `content_css: ['//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower'],` does is to add a link into the content iframe, so nothing outside of that iframe has access to the font. The easiest fix is just to add a link to your font stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower">
```

into the head of your main document as well as using the `content_css`parameter in your TinyMCE initialisation, as you can see here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMwwrG

Comment: Mmm this is a good point, so you've just added a external CSS outside the TinyMCE editor `<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower">`will try this option. Many thanks

Comment: You'll still need it as the `content_css` param as well for the content iframe, but yeah absolutely

Comment: I've it working! Many thanks for the suggestion, i've used `window.parent.$("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.quiter.com/fonts/' + brandList[i] + '/' + brandList[i] + '.css">');`and works like a charm. Enjoy the bounty you have earned ;)

Comment: Happy to help, and much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

tinyMCE does not state clearly on their [font-format](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#font_formats) documentation (super short and quite meaningless). The link mentioned by @skobaljic, is from this [question](https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000QdFKAA0), and you can notice that even their developer uses "cursive"(generic family) instead of "indie flower".

Base on my own experience, tinyMCE can only display the generic family or font built in by **your browser**.

Lets say in chrome:

> Agency FB; Aharoni; Algerian; Andalus; Angsana New; AngsanaUPC;
>   Aparajita; Arabic Typesetting; Arial; Arial Black; Arial Narrow; Arial
>   Rounded MT Bold; Baskerville Old Face; Batang; BatangChe; Bauhaus 93;
>   Bell MT; Berlin Sans FB; Berlin Sans FB Demi; Bernard MT Condensed;
>   Blackadder ITC; Bodoni MT; Bodoni MT Black; Bodoni MT Condensed;
>   Bodoni MT Poster Compressed; Book Antiqua; Bookman Old Style;
>   Bookshelf Symbol 7; Bradley Hand ITC; Britannic Bold; Broadway;
>   Browallia New; BrowalliaUPC; Brush Script MT; Calibri; Calibri Light;
>   Californian FB; Calisto MT; Cambria; Cambria Math; Candara; Castellar;
>   Centaur; Century; Century Gothic; Century Schoolbook; Chiller; Colonna
>   MT; Comic Sans MS; Consolas; Constantia; Cooper Black; Copperplate
>   Gothic Bold; Copperplate Gothic Light; Corbel; Cordia New; CordiaUPC;
>   Courier; Courier New; Curlz MT; DaunPenh; David; DilleniaUPC;
>   DokChampa; Dotum; DotumChe; Dubai; Dubai Light; Dubai Medium; Ebrima;
>   Edwardian Script ITC; Elephant; Engravers MT; Eras Bold ITC; Eras Demi
>   ITC; Eras Light ITC; Eras Medium ITC; Estrangelo Edessa; EucrosiaUPC;
>   Euphemia; FangSong; Felix Titling; Fixedsys; Footlight MT Light;
>   Forte; FrankRuehl; Franklin Gothic Book; Franklin Gothic Demi;
>   Franklin Gothic Demi Cond; Franklin Gothic Heavy; Franklin Gothic
>   Medium; Franklin Gothic Medium Cond; FreesiaUPC; Freestyle Script;
>   French Script MT; Gabriola; Gadugi; Garamond; Gautami; Georgia; Gigi;
>   Gill Sans MT; Gill Sans MT Condensed; Gill Sans MT Ext Condensed Bold;
>   Gill Sans Ultra Bold; Gill Sans Ultra Bold Condensed; Gisha;
>   Gloucester MT Extra Condensed; Goudy Old Style; Goudy Stout; Gulim;
>   GulimChe; Gungsuh; GungsuhChe; Haettenschweiler; Harlow Solid Italic;
>   Harrington; High Tower Text; Impact; Imprint MT Shadow; Informal
>   Roman; IrisUPC; Iskoola Pota; JasmineUPC; Jokerman; Juice ITC; KaiTi;
>   Kalinga; Kartika; Khmer UI; KodchiangUPC; Kokila; Kristen ITC;
>   Kunstler Script; Lao UI; Latha; Leelawadee; Levenim MT; LilyUPC;
>   Lucida Bright; Lucida Calligraphy; Lucida Console; Lucida Fax; Lucida
>   Handwriting; Lucida Sans; Lucida Sans Typewriter; Lucida Sans Unicode;
>   MS Gothic; MS Mincho; MS Outlook; MS PGothic; MS PMincho; MS Reference
>   Sans Serif; MS Reference Specialty; MS Sans Serif; MS Serif; MS UI
>   Gothic; MT Extra; MV Boli; Magneto; Maiandra GD; Malgun Gothic;
>   Mangal; Marlett; Matura MT Script Capitals; Meiryo; Meiryo UI;
>   Microsoft Himalaya; Microsoft JhengHei UI; Microsoft New Tai Lue;
>   Microsoft PhagsPa; Microsoft Sans Serif; Microsoft Tai Le; Microsoft
>   Uighur; Microsoft YaHei; Microsoft YaHei UI; Microsoft Yi Baiti;
>   Miriam; Miriam Fixed; Mistral; Modern; Modern No. 20; Mongolian Baiti;
>   Monotype Corsiva; MoolBoran; NSimSun; Narkisim; Niagara Engraved;
>   Niagara Solid; Nirmala UI; Nyala; OCR A Extended; Old English Text MT;
>   Onyx; Palace Script MT; Palatino Linotype; Papyrus; Parchment;
>   Perpetua; Perpetua Titling MT; Plantagenet Cherokee; Playbill; Poor
>   Richard; Pristina; Raavi; Rage Italic; Ravie; Rockwell; Rockwell
>   Condensed; Rockwell Extra Bold; Rod; Roman; Sakkal Majalla; Script;
>   Script MT Bold; Segoe Print; Segoe Script; Segoe UI; Segoe UI Light;
>   Segoe UI Semibold; Segoe UI Semilight; Segoe UI Symbol; Shonar Bangla;
>   Showcard Gothic; Shruti; SimHei; SimSun; SimSun-ExtB; Simplified
>   Arabic; Simplified Arabic Fixed; Small Fonts; Snap ITC; Stencil;
>   Sylfaen; Symbol; System; Tahoma; Tempus Sans ITC; Terminal; Times New
>   Roman; Traditional Arabic; Trebuchet MS; Tunga; Tw Cen MT; Tw Cen MT
>   Condensed; Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold; Utsaah; Vani; Verdana;
>   Vijaya; Viner Hand ITC; Vivaldi; Vladimir Script; Vrinda; Webdings;
>   Wide Latin; Wingdings; Wingdings 2; Wingdings 3; 微軟正黑體; 新細明體;
>   新細明體-ExtB; 標楷體; 細明體; 細明體-ExtB; 細明體_HKSCS; 細明體_HKSCS-ExtB

You **can** add any new fonts to your browser, however the effect only works on your computer or others who has the same font supported in their browser.

The reason why your content display all correct fonts is: after tinyMCE rendered its staff, it outputs the option telling the js to find the font you want (lets say NewFontName, and if content_css provided, go content_css find that font), but **itself didn't load the font you imported**.

Comment: So you're getting the same result as me, impossible to set font-family style to the dropdown :(. Thanks for your information @MatrixTai

Comment: I believe you can customize the js of tinyMCE, load the font you want inside the tinyMCE class...well, I am quite lazy for this and thus give up. @IgnacioAra

Comment: What do you mean with _load the fotn you want inside the tinyMCE class_ i'm loading the *.css file inside the initialization. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for using confusing wording, I should not use the word "load". tinyMCE only 'check' the font style you input with the browser supported, while those cant support will be thrown away. Therefore, I guess (guess only) you can alter the js file of tinyMCE for adding more supported font.